# SQL query to exclude records that appear in other rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am not sure how to word this question but here is the issue.

I have a table `subscribers` of emails that looks like this:

```
Email - Event_id
1@1.com - 123
1@1.com - 456
2@2.com - 123
3@3.com - 123
3@3.com - 123
```

I have a query that looks like this:

```
select email as "Email Address"

from subscribers

where event_id='123'

GROUP BY email
```

I want the result of this query to be:

```
Email Address
2@2.com
3@3.com
```

But obviously based on the query I have I get:

```
Email Address
1@1.com
2@2.com
3@3.com
```

Basically I would like to exclude emails that are associated with other event IDs and only collect those that appear in ONLY event with ID `123`

Comment: Why mysql & sqlserver tags? which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I guess I must be mistaken in beliveing they are the same thing? I am using a mysql server and I thought sql-server was the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter results you are not interested in using `IN`:

```
select email as "Email Address"
from subscribers
where event_id='123' 
      and email not in(
          select email as "Email Address"
          from subscribers
          where event_id<>'123')
group by email
```

Comment: I am trying this now, but just to clarify is that an example of a sub query?

Answer (score 4):

Just use a `having` clause and move the condition there:

```
select email as "Email Address"
from subscribers
group by email
having min(event_id) = max(event_id) and min(event_id) = '123';
```

This says that the minimum event_id on the email is the same as the maximum (hence all are equal or `NULL`) and the value is `'123'`.

Comment: Out of the box thinking - nice one :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT email as "Email Address"
FROM subscribers s
WHERE event_id ='123'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT email
                  FROM subcribers s1
                  WHERE event_id <> '123'
                    AND s1.email = s.email)
GROUP BY email
```

Comment: @YosiDahari Sorry, i was working with exists and  your didnt work when i try because need some inside comparasion.